# Variable not visible in if block

Tags: common-lisp

```
(let ((x 21) (y 7)) 
  (princ (/ x y)) 
  (let z 
    (/ x y) 
    (if (eq z 3)(princ "Working"))))
```

My intention for this program is to have "Working" be printed out when z is equal to 3, where I assumed that z will be visible(from the let z) in the if block; however, that is not the case and the error reads as:

> -IF: variable Z has no value.

Is there a way for me to have the variable z be visible in the if block?

Thank you.

Comment: When something doesn't work check each of the components, one by one, to find where exactly is the problem. Like here, you could've checked the inner `let` for `x=21` and `y=7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a set of parenthesis around the declaration of `z`.

```
(let ((x 21) 
      (y 7)) 
  (princ (/ x y)) 
  (let ((z (/ x y)))
    (if (eq z 3)
      (princ "Working")))) ;; Working
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `LET` syntax is incorrect. The first parameter to `LET` is supposed to be a list of variable bindings:

```
(let ((var1 val1)
      (var2 val2)
      ...)
  body)
```

Within the list of bindings you can have just `varN` instead of `(varN valN)`, which is short for `(varN nil)`.

But you don't have a list at all, you just have the symbol `Z` where the list of bindings should be. That's not valid (I'm surprised you didn't get a syntax error because of it). I suspect you meant:

```
(let ((z (/ x y)))
  (if (eq z 3) (princ "Working")))
```

BTW, you shouldn't use `eq` to compare numbers -- use `=`.

Comment: `eql` evaluates to `nil` if types are different (`eql 1 1.0` -> `nil`). proper way to compare numerical values is `=` (or `equalp` which uses `=` to compare numbers).

Comment: @rsm True, but there's nothing here that would produce floats. I changed my answer to be specific to rational numbers.

Comment: as long as `x` and `y` are integers `eql` works in this case. but i still don't think it's a good idea to advise on using 'eql` to compare numerical values in general. also `=` makes intention clear, 'eql' does not. (oh, and about your edit - he is comparing integers here, not rationals:)

Comment: @rsm Dividing integers can produce rationals, e.g. `(/ 5 2) => 5/2`. But I've changed the answer to only recommend `=`.

Comment: Actually dividing integers will always produce rationals, which is a superclass of integers and ratios. `5/2` is a `RATIO` (and less specifically a `RATIONAL`).

Comment: @jkiiski dividing integers CAN produce rationals, but don't have to. `(/ 4 2) => 2` and `(type-of (/ 4 2)) => INTEGER`. that's because CL will not only upgrade type like most languages do when they have to perform some computations on the same types, but will also DOWNGRADE type when there is no need for more complicated one anymore (ie CL will never have `4/2` ratio, it will be automatically downgraded to integer, which is pretty neat if you ask me :)

Comment: @rsm My point was that integers are rationals. `(typep 2 'rational)` => `t`. The result of `/` when the arguments are rationals (whether `INTEGER`s or `RATIO`s) will always be a `RATIONAL`.

Comment: Right, `RATIONAL = (UNION INTEGER RATIO)`. The point I was trying to make in my original wording was the distinction between `EQ` and `EQL`, not necessarily point out the best comparison operator for all situations.